# How to find the full list of magic (dunder) methods in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I wonder if there exists a full list of the available magic (dunder) methods in Python? I searched online and on Python's website and got no such a list.

I also wonder can user define new magic (dunder) methods in Python? I understand I can define methods with underscores in their names, for example, `__hello__()`. But I wonder how can I assign special functionalities (such as `__add__()` is called with operator `+`) for those user-defined magic methods? Say how do I ask python objects to automatically call `__hello__()` method when they are used with operator `$$` (a random example)?

Comment: It’s in the [documentation …](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Comment: @donkopotamus Thanks! This is what I'm looking for!